# Creating multiple files for for-loop outputs

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

I'm quite a beginner in R so I hope this question is interesting to most of you.

Here's a sample of the `collar` file I'm working with:

```
     observed predicted probability results1
1     Head-up   Grazing   0.2727273 NEGATIVE
2     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE
3     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE
4     Head-up   Grazing   0.5454545 NEGATIVE
5     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727 NEGATIVE
6     Head-up   Grazing   0.4545455 NEGATIVE
7     Head-up Vigilance   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
8     Head-up   Grazing   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
9     Head-up Vigilance   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
10    Unknown   Grazing   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
11     Moving   Head-up   0.4545455 NEGATIVE
12     Moving   Grazing   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
13    Head-up   Grazing   0.4545455 NEGATIVE
14    Head-up   Grazing   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
15    Head-up   Grazing   0.4545455 NEGATIVE
16    Head-up   Grazing   0.3636364 NEGATIVE
17    Head-up   Head-up   0.4545455 POSITIVE
18    Head-up   Grazing   0.2727273 NEGATIVE
```

Next, I intended to create a `for` loop that will add a 5th column `"results2"`. Because the outcome of the 5th column `"results2"` depends on a `i` value ranging from 0 to 1 and increasing of 0.1, I want to create multiple Excel files for each `i` value (where `i=0`, `i=0.1` etc. until `i=1`). Here's what I've been trying so far:

```
#Creating the for loop for column results 2 with i [0:1] increasing of 0.1. The file collar is the full file from the sample above.

for (i in seq(0, 1, by = 0.1))
{collar$results2<-mutate(collar,results2 = case_when( (probability > i & results1 == "POSITIVE") | (probability < i & results1 == "NEGATIVE") ~ TRUE, TRUE ~ FALSE) )
as.character(collar$results2)

#Writing down Excel files for each i value
collaraccuracy1=paste('collar41361_41365', i, 'csv', sep = '.')
write.csv(collaraccuracy1)}
```

This is what is printed by R when running the loop. Names are exactly as I want them to be:

```
"","x"
"1","collar41361_41365.0.csv"
"","x"
"1","collar41361_41365.0.1.csv"
"","x"
"1","collar41361_41365.0.2.csv"
"","x"
"1","collar41361_41365.0.3.csv"
"","x"
"1","collar41361_41365.0.4.csv"
"","x"
"1","collar41361_41365.0.5.csv"
"","x"
"1","collar41361_41365.0.6.csv"
"","x"
"1","collar41361_41365.0.7.csv"
"","x"
"1","collar41361_41365.0.8.csv"
"","x"
"1","collar41361_41365.0.9.csv"
"","x"
"1","collar41361_41365.1.csv"
```

However, I can't find the files anywhere in my computer and I'm wondering if formulated the `write.csv` function correctly..

Any tips? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In your `write.csv`, 'x' argument is not present.  The `file` argument would be `collaraccuracy1`'.  Perhaps `x` is `collar`? i.e. `write.csv(x = collar, collaraccuracy1)}`

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `write.csv` needs an object parameter 'x' which is not provided in the loop.  It senses 'collaraccuracy1' as the `file`.

```
...
    write.csv(x = collar, collaraccuracy1)
  }
```