# Formatting multiple files at once in R

Tags: r, for-loop, formatting

I'm quite new to R so I hope this question will still be interesting. I created a `for` loop which produced 11 csv files. Here's the code I used for that in case that could help clarify the question:

```
for (i in seq(0, 1, by = 0.1))
{collar$results2<-mutate(collar,results2 = case_when( (probability > i & results1 == "POSITIVE") | (probability < i & results1 == "NEGATIVE") ~ TRUE, TRUE ~ FALSE) )
as.character(collar$results2)
collaraccuracy1=paste('collar41361_41365', i, 'csv', sep = '.')
write.csv(collar,collaraccuracy1)}
```

As you can see, all files created have the following format: `collar41361_41365.i.csv`, with ``i` ranging from 0 to 1 every 0.1, like so:

```
[1] "collar41361_41365.0.csv"
[1] "collar41361_41365.0.1.csv"
[1] "collar41361_41365.0.2.csv"
[1] "collar41361_41365.0.3.csv"
[1] "collar41361_41365.0.4.csv"
[1] "collar41361_41365.0.5.csv"
[1] "collar41361_41365.0.6.csv"
[1] "collar41361_41365.0.7.csv"
[1] "collar41361_41365.0.8.csv"
[1] "collar41361_41365.0.9.csv"
[1] "collar41361_41365.1.csv"
```

Now, I'd like to format all the files at one since they have the same structure (10 columns, 240 rows and same column header) and same name format.

See below the code with the actions I've been trying take over this 11 files. I've used `Sys.glob` as this was mentionned to be the best way to perform the task in another post. I've previously coded this actions for a single file and it worked. I now want to apply the code for all 11 files at once:

```
#1) Reading multiple files at one. Now, this will only work for the files with a decimal value of i in their name -which is fine-. If I was reading files with i=0 or i=1, then we'll have the pattern "collar41361_41365.*.csv". Am I right?

collaraccuracy<-lapply(Sys.glob("collar41361_41365.***.csv"), read.csv)

#2) Select only the columns with header "observed","predicted","probability","results1","results2.results2"

collaraccuracy<-fread("collar41361_41365.***.csv",select=c("observed","predicted","probability","results1","results2.results2"),stringsAsFactors = F)

#3) Rename column "results2.results2" to "results2"

colnames(collaraccuracy)<-c("observed","predicted","probability","results1","results2")

#4) Create 6th column "results" by merging columns "results1" and "results2"

collaraccuracy$results <- paste(collaraccuracy$results2, 
collaraccuracy$results1,sep="_")


#5) End of the formatting. Write new formated csv files with the pattern "collar41361_by_41365.i.csv"

collaraccuracy2=paste('collar41361_by_41365', i, 'csv', sep = '.')
write.csv(collaraccuracy,collaraccuracy2)
```

As you can see, I've 5 different actions to compute the should end up with eventually 9 files for i values of (0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9)

I'm specially concerned with the syntax in actions 1) and 2), but this is the best I can do so far.

Any tips to formulate this? Any help is appreciated!

P.S. Update: I've tried to create a function and applying it to the rest of the files with `lapply`:

```
collarcolumns<-function(collaraccuracy1)
{collaraccuracy1<-fread(("collar41361_41365.1.csv"),select=c("observed","predicted","probability","results1","results2.results2"),stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(collaraccuracy1)<-c("observed","predicted","probability","results1","results2")
collaraccuracy1$results <- paste(collaraccuracy1$results2, collaraccuracy1$results1,sep="_")
collaraccuracy2=paste('collar41361_by_41365', i, 'csv', sep = '.')
write.csv(collaraccuracy1,collaraccuracy2)}

lapply(Sys.glob("collar41361_41365.*.csv"), collarcolumns)
```

And got 11 `"NULL"`s printed by R.. Was I on the right track?

Comment: You seem to like deleting and reposting your questions. If a post isn't clear, simply edit it not delete and repost. The more posts you delete, the higher the chances of getting banned from asking. Also accepting answers is one way to help avoid the ban(I think) and it's common courtesy.

Comment: This is an earlier question of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649526/creating-multiple-files-for-for-loop-outputs

Comment: @NelsonGon Thank you for your comment. I'm a bit confused by your statement since I've never deleted a previous question, as I understand others might benefit from the shared information. I've also never reposted a question. I'm sorry if asking a new question on the same script is a problem, but both questions are relative to very different problems I've had while creating the script. I simply think is more informative to post two separate questions even if they belong to the creation of the same script, rather than editing a previous question which original information might be lost.

Comment: @NelsonGon I agree on the fact the accepting answers is very important part of the dynamics of this forum. Thank you for the reminder and I encourage every user to accept and vote answers and comments.

Comment: It seems to me that it would be easier to do all this manipulation in that first for loop, and write to csvs only after you've formatted the data exactly as you want it.  Would that approach work for your problem?

Comment: @A.S.K. Of course, that would be also an option. How would you put this two `for` loops in one though? Was I on very bad path the way I was trying at first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a step back, it sounds like you want to do the following for each `i`:

- Add a column `results2` that checks whether the predicted value matches the observed value with probability `i`.
- Add a column `results` that concatenates `results1` and `results2`.

The reason you're seeing strange column names like `results2.results2` is that the original `for` loop is redundant; you don't need both an assignment statement (`collar$results2 <- ...`) and `mutate`.  We can strip the whole thing down to one loop, like this:

```
for(i in seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)) {
  collar.temp = collar %>%
    mutate(results2 = case_when((probability > i & results1 == "POSITIVE") |
                                  (probability < i & results1 == "NEGATIVE") ~ T,
                                T ~ F)) %>%
    mutate(results = paste(results1, results2, sep = "_"))
  collaraccuracy1 = paste('collar41361_41365', i, 'csv', sep = '.')
  write.csv(collar.temp, collaraccuracy1)
}
```

Taking yet a further step back, are you sure you want 11 separate tables?  It looks to me like you're effectively checking how accurate the predictions are at various "confidence" cutoffs.  One way to put the data into a tidy format would be like this, where `cutoff` is its own column:

```
collar.tidy = do.call(
  "bind_rows",
  lapply(
    seq(0, 1, by = 0.1),
    function(x) {
      collar %>%
        mutate(cutoff = x,
               results2 = case_when((probability > x & results1 == "POSITIVE") |
                                      (probability < x & results1 == "NEGATIVE") ~ T,
                                    T ~ F)) %>%
        mutate(results = paste(results1, results2, sep = "_"))
    }
  )
)
```

See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) for a great introduction to tidy data.  You may think of other ways to tidy up this dataset; for example, it's not clear to me whether the `results` column that concatenates two other columns is strictly necessary.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I'm trying to do indeed. I'll give this a look and get back to you.